# Is is possible to run two docker applications (multi images) using AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run two Docker applications in single EC2 instance using Elastic Beanstalk.
I am aware about the multiple docker containers. But is deploying two images using EB possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html)

You'll need to define a [Dockerrun.aws.json v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun) file with each of your containers needed to run your application. From there you'll need to bundle in each Dockerfile that will be needed with your zip file to be deployed.